# How to add Assembly-References on a per-configuration-basis

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm currently looking to add some debug only code to a windows phone project. This debug code will drag in some debug class library references (nunit helpers) and some WCF service client references, and I'd really like to not have these referenced in the release build.

Can anyone suggest any way that I can add an Assembly-Reference to debug, but not have it appear in release?

<strike>I've seen this on Connect - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/106011/allow-adding-assembly-references-on-a-per-configuration-basis-debug-release - but it's marked as "postponed"</strike>

There's a request on Visual Studio's UserVoice but it is marked as `Closed` as `Won't Fix` here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2062487-allow-assembly-references-to-switch-based-on-confi

Comment: Ooh, nice question. Is this possible with some MSBuild trickery, perhaps?

Comment: I think you might need to have two project files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both cases using MSBuild `Condition`, you've once configure `csproj` and forget about this.

**First:** Using `Condition`

1. Create new project DebugOnlyHelpers
2. Reference all Debug-specific helpers in this project
3. Specify a Condition in `csproj` file where need to filter references:

---

```
<ProjectReference 
            Include="DebugOnlyHelpers.csproj"
            Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DEBUG' "
```

**Second:**  Using `Condition` together with [Choose/When](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164289.aspx):

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG' ">
        <ItemGroup>
             <Reference Include="NUnit.dll" />
             <Reference Include="Standard.dll" />
         </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
         <ItemGroup>
             <Reference Include="Standard.dll" />
         </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - +1 added - I'm testing and will hopefully be back to tick it soon :)

Comment: Here's a newer link to [Choose/When](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score -5):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this right now. You'll have to switch to debug and remove the reference, then add it back when you return to release.

Comment: I didn't know of the MSBuild solution, but there's certainly no clean way to do it in Visual Studio itself.