# asp.net publish - do not copy web.config to output directory

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is it possible to not include web.config in output directory, but still use web.config during building the application?

Unfortunatelly setting **Build action** to **"None"** doesn't copy web.config but application cannot compile because web.config is not used then.

Comment: In the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659460/how-to-add-assembly-references-on-a-per-configuration-basis the second option tells you how to include files only in Debug or Release - you could try that and make the web.config file only part of Debug. You'd use Debug locally then publish in Release

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look into web.config *transformations*.

They allow you to have one version for debug and one for release (deployment).

The most common transformation is for connection strings. You can do that like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="local" connectionString="Data Source=IPAddress,Port;Initial Catalog=SomeOtherDB;User ID=TopSecretUsername;Password=SecurePassword" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Another very common transformation is removing the debug attribute for release:

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

Read more here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

A great (free) video course can be found here:
http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/table-of-contents/aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Comment: I want run my application with web.config, however I do not want to copy it to publish directory where other web.config already is.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Can you do something like what's suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659460/how-to-add-assembly-references-on-a-per-configuration-basis)?

something like replacing in your prj file where you find the include for web.config with (untested):

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='DEBUG' ">
        <ItemGroup>
             <Reference Include="web.config" />
         </ItemGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

As Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu so 'Angryly' puts it - unless you have a good reason to really want the file not to be copies rather then use transformations, you should go with transformations. If you really have to not copy the file or transformations are not suited for your needs, you can try this one

Comment: Your answer is totally unrelated to ASP.NET. Such projects don't even have a .prj file. The only built-in solution to the OP's issue is web.config transformations.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu Well it does for me VS2013 - if i create an C# ASP Net project it creates a csproj file - if i create a VB NET ASP Net project it createa a vbproj file - i do admit transformations might probably be a best fit for the problem depending on why the OP doesn't want the file copied but he did ask about not publishing it - and that was what i answered

Comment: That .csproj file (not .prj as you have stated) is used for build, not deployment. And we're talking about deployment here :)

Comment: i said prj cause i don't know if the OP is using C# or VB Net - obviously

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu have you even tested my solution at all to say ASP Net won't look into the project file to know what the hell to publish in the first place?

Comment: If you haven't tested it why should I? I know for a fact that web.config transformations are the way to achieve such things and all  developers with a clue of ASP.NET will agree.

Comment: And so did i - as you can see clearly in my comment above - but all developers with a clue of ASP NET know these projects HAVE a project file - and you already had answered transformations - so i gave a valid alternative case the OP couldn't use transformations on their specific issue